# Php check if shell_exec command was successful

Tags: php, shell, command-line, command, shell-exec

I basically want to check if a command ran successfully using `shell_exec`.

Simple function:

```
public static function foo()
{
    $command = "blabla";
    shell_exec($command);
}
```

Edit, I tried Mister M's suggestion like this:

```
foreach($commands as $key => $value)
{
    shell_exec($value, $output, $return);
}
```

And I get this error:

> Undefined variable: output

Answer (score 10):

Try using `exec`:

```
$output = array();//Each line will be assigned to this array if any are generated.
$result1 = exec($command, $output, $return);

if ($return != 0)
{
 // error occurred
}
else
{
 // success
}
```

Comment: I do not have to define $output nor $return correct ?

Comment: are you redirecting stderr? I mean add this to the end of your $command: "2>&1" so it's like "your command 2>&1"

Answer (score 3):

You should use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead of `shell_exec` if you need only the exit code of the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

and validate the output.

But according to the manual:

> Note:
>   This function can return **NULL** both when an error occurs or the program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is required.

http://php.net/shell_exec

Answer (score 0):

It would depend whether your command returns any output. According to [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

> shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

and:

> Return Values
>
> The output from the executed command or NULL if an error occurred or
>   the command produces no output.
>
> Note: This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the
>   program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution
>   failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the
>   program exit code is required.

So, if you can expect the output in your command to appear, just catch the return value of shell_exec function.